# Upgrade to dotnet 3.1 from 2.2 causes transactions insert foreign key issues when adding to 2 different tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have an API that used to be dotnet 2.2 that we have upgraded directly to 3.1. When a route would be called to add a new file to the db, it would create 2 different entities in a transaction and call SaveChangesAsync() after.

```
await _unitOfWork.PublicationFiles.CreateAsync(file);
await _unitOfWork.PublicationFileContents.CreateAsync(new PublicationFileContent { FileId = file.FileId, FileContent = fileContents.ElementAt(index) });
await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync(); //This just calls _context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

As you see, the second entity relies on the fileid of the first entity to be generated. It seems like 2.2 would do the calls one after the next and it would work.

The error is:

> ERROR The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PublicationFileContent_PublicationFiles". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE", table "dbo.PublicationFiles", column 'FileId'.

Here is the modelBuilder for both entities:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<PublicationFile> (entity => {
                entity.HasKey (e => e.FileId)
                    .IsClustered (false);

                entity.HasIndex (e => e.DownloadDate)
                    .HasName ("IX_PublicationFilesDownloadDate")
                    .IsClustered ();

                entity.HasIndex (e => e.ParseStatus)
                    .HasName ("IX_PublicationFilesParseStatus");

                entity.HasIndex (e => new { e.FileName, e.PublicationId })
                    .HasName ("IX_PublicationFiles_PublicationId");

                entity.Property (e => e.DownloadDate).HasColumnType ("datetime");

                entity.Property (e => e.FileDate).HasColumnType ("datetime");

                entity.Property (e => e.FileName).HasMaxLength (255);

                entity.Property (e => e.ParseEnd).HasColumnType ("datetime");

                entity.Property (e => e.ParseServer).HasMaxLength (50);

                entity.Property (e => e.ParseStart).HasColumnType ("datetime");

                entity.Property (e => e.ProvidedDate).HasColumnType ("datetime");

                entity.HasOne (d => d.Publication)
                    .WithMany (p => p.PublicationFiles)
                    .HasForeignKey (d => d.PublicationId)
                    .HasConstraintName ("FK_PublicationFiles_Publications");
            });
 modelBuilder.Entity<PublicationFileContent> (entity => {
                entity.HasKey (e => e.FileId);

                entity.ToTable ("PublicationFileContent");

                entity.Property (e => e.FileId).ValueGeneratedNever ();

                entity.HasOne (d => d.File)
                    .WithOne (p => p.PublicationFileContent)
                    .HasForeignKey<PublicationFileContent> (d => d.FileId)
                    .HasConstraintName ("FK_PublicationFileContent_PublicationFiles");
            });
```

How can I fix this to work in the same transactions for rollback purposes? I need to ensure both entities are created or no entities is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. There was a breaking change in dotnet 3.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#temporary-key-values-are-no-longer-set-onto-entity-instances

Had to change my second create line to use the navigation property instead of the id.

```
await _unitOfWork.PublicationFileContents.CreateAsync(new PublicationFileContent { FileId = file, FileContent = fileContents.ElementAt(index) });
```